# how find the last text node of the <p> element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

in the following code snippet I need to get the text node which is the last child element.

```
<p class="western" style="margin-bottom: 0.14in">
  <font color="#000000">
    <font face="Arial, serif">
      <font size="1" style="font-size: 8pt">
        <b>The value conclusion of the Income Approach</b>
     </font>
    </font>
  </font>
</p>
```

I need to select the text node `The value conclusion of the Income Approach`, the only accessible is `<p>`, the elements inside the `<p>` tag are dynamic.

this is another html.

```
<p class="western" style="margin-bottom: 0.14in">
  <font color="#000000"><font face="Arial, serif">
    <font size="1" style="font-size: 8pt">The client has specifically....</font>
 </font>
</p>
```

In the above snippet I need to select `The client has specifically....`

the code I tried

```
var $html = `<div>
                            <p class="western" style="margin-bottom: 0.14in">
                              <font color="#000000"><font face="Arial, serif">
                                <font size="1" style="font-size: 8pt">The client has specifically....</font>
                             </font>
                            </p>
                            <p class="western" style="margin-bottom: 0.14in">
                                <font color="#000000"><font face="Arial, serif">
                                    <font size="1" style="font-size: 8pt">The client has specifically....</font>
                                </font>
                            </p>
                        </div>`;

                $html.find('p').each(function(){

                    $(this).contents().filter(function(){
                        return this.nodeType === 3; // Text node
                    }).each(function(){

                        var f = $(this).parent().css('font-size');

                        if(f && f.trim() != '')
                            $(this).closest('p').css('font-size', f);
                    });                    
                });
```

my intention is give same font size to `<p>` element by its own text node

Comment: Is it possible to have something other than `<font>` as the last child?

Comment: @SalmanA yes, that html snippet is coming from a rtf to html converter, I need give same font size to <p> as its text node font-size

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming *the last child element* is the last element having no child nodes, you can do this:

```js
$(function() {
  $("p").each(function() {
    var $lastelem = $(this).find("*").filter(function() {
      // count children instead of childNodes
      return this.children.length === 0;
    }).last();
    console.log(this, $lastelem.get(0), $lastelem.css("font-size"));
  });
});
```

```html
<!--
WARNING: enabling stacksnippets console causes this
script to stall. Do not enable "show console", look
at your browser's console instead.
-->

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<p class="western" style="margin-bottom: 0.14in">
  <font color="#000000">
    <font face="Arial, serif">
      <font size="1" style="font-size: 8pt">
        <b>The value conclusion of the Income Approach</b>
      </font>
    </font>
  </font>
</p>

<p class="western" style="margin-bottom: 0.14in">
  <font color="#000000">
    <font face="Arial, serif">
      <font size="1" style="font-size: 8pt">The client has specifically....</font>
    </font>
  </font>
</p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a selector string to find all elements with a `style` attribute which are descendants of a `p`. Check that the attribute has a `font-size` and that something is inside the element, then go back up to the `p`:

```js
$('p [style]')
  .each(function() {
    const $this = $(this);
    if ($this.text().trim()) {
      const fontSize = $(this).css('font-size');
      if (fontSize.trim()) {
        $this.closest('p').css('font-size', fontSize);
      }
    }
  });

console.log(document.body.innerHTML);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="western" style="margin-bottom: 0.14in">
  <font color="#000000">
    <font face="Arial, serif">
      <font size="1" style="font-size: 8pt">
        <b>The value conclusion of the Income Approach</b>
      </font>
    </font>
  </font>
</p>


<p class="western" style="margin-bottom: 0.14in">
  <font color="#000000">
    <font face="Arial, serif">
      <font size="1" style="font-size: 8pt">The client has specifically....</font>
    </font>
  </font>
</p>
```

Comment: cannot use `'p font[style]` as selector there might `p > b` tags the only selector can be used is `$('p')`

Comment: Just remove the `font` part then

Comment: that html snippet is coming from a rtf to html converter, I need give same font size to `<p>` as its text node font-size

Comment: the only selector I can is `$('p')`

Comment: Why? Since you only want to find elements which have ancestors with `style`s, `p [style]` is the better way to go

Comment: If it's not working for you, please edit more examples into the question, so we can see what exactly the issue is

Answer (score 0):

See if this small code helps you.

```js
var $target = $('p.western').children();

while ($target.length) {
    $target = $target.children();
}

console.log($target.end().text());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="western" style="margin-bottom: 0.14in">
  <font color="#000000">
    <font face="Arial, serif">
      <font size="1" style="font-size: 8pt">
        <b>The value conclusion of the Income Approach</b>
     </font>
    </font>
  </font>
</p>
```

```js
var $target = $('p.western').children();

while ($target.length) {
    $target = $target.children();
}

console.log($target.end().text());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p class="western" style="margin-bottom: 0.14in">
  <font color="#000000"><font face="Arial, serif">
    <font size="1" style="font-size: 8pt">The client has specifically....</font>
 </font>
</p>
```